# Finding Number of people using sql query in tree structure

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures

I have table structure like this, it's like tree structure, how to find out number of people's are the under particular referreid, Reffered id is nothing but clientId, I tried with couple of methods but it's going nested loop...

```
     Id    ClientId ReferreId
     1  1   2
     2  3   2
     3  4   1
     4  5   1
     5  6   3
     6  7   3
     7  8   4
     8  9   4
     9  10  5
     10 11  5
     11 12  6
     12 13  6
     13 14  7
     14 15  7
```

Comment: Question not clear client id referred id is same so y two fields ??

Comment: It's like binary tree structure, assume that Reffere Id 2 is node, it has two child like 1,3. And 1 and 3 as Node , it has two child, namely 4,5 and 6, 7 etc...., it's keep on going like nested loop @Bunny,@ViSu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4b7a/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table YourTable
(
  Id int,
  ClientId int,
  ReferreId int
);

insert into YourTable values
(1  ,1   ,2),
(2  ,3   ,2),
(3  ,4   ,1),
(4  ,5   ,1),
(5  ,6   ,3),
(6  ,7   ,3),
(7  ,8   ,4),
(8  ,9   ,4),
(9  ,10  ,5),
(10 ,11  ,5),
(11 ,12  ,6),
(12 ,13  ,6),
(13 ,14  ,7),
(14 ,15  ,7);
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
declare @ReferreId int;
set @ReferreId = 2;

with C as
(
  select T.Id,
         T.ClientId,
         T.ReferreId
  from YourTable as T
  where T.ReferreId = @ReferreId
  union all
  select T.Id,
         T.ClientId,
         T.ReferreId
  from YourTable as T
    inner join C
      on T.ReferreId = C.ClientId
)
select count(*) as ChildCount
from C
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4b7a/1/0)**:

```
| CHILDCOUNT |
|------------|
|         14 |
```